# is there any way to split function code to another file or component?

Tags: reactjs

you can see code below, **myFunc** have a very long code. is there any way to split this code to another file or component? thx

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react'
 export default class Untitled-1 extends Component {
    state = {
       first: true,
       slideIndex: "2",
    }
    myFunc(){
      if(this.state.slideIndex === "2"){
         // do stuff
      }else {
         // do stuff
      }
      //this function have a long long code
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => this.myFunc()}>click me</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a separate `doStuff.js`

```
const doStuff = (slideIndex) => {
    if (slideIndex === '2') {
        // do some logic
        // maybe return something
    }
    ...
})
export default doStuff
```

Then in your component just import it

```
import doStuff from './doStuff.js';
...
myFunc() {
    doStuff(this.state.slideIndex);
...
```

**Manipulating State from the Helper**

Helper

```
const doStuff = (slideIndex, cb) => {
    if (slideIndex === '2') {
        // do some logic
        cb('slideIndex is now this!')
    }
    ...
})
export default doStuff
```

Main Component

```
import doStuff from './doStuff.js';
...
myFunc() {
    doStuff(this.state.slideIndex, (result) => this.setState({slideIndex: result});
...
```

Comment: thx for the quick reply, one question is how to apply this.setState({slideIndex:"1"}) in doStuff.js ? thx

Comment: It may be better to just return the value from `doStuff` and then set the state in the parent component. Otherwise, you can create a function to set the state within the parent component, then pass the function as a prop to doStuff and call it as such.

Comment: sorry for my ignorant but can you show me code for pass the function as a prop to doStuff? what i know is only pass function as a prop to child component like this: <Navigation state={this.changeState.bind(this)} /> . thx again for the quick reply

Comment: sorry I meant you can pass it as a callback `doStuff(this.state.slideIndex, (result) => this.setState({slideIndex: result}))`

Comment: @caberg added an example of what it could look like to the answer